# How to Sort a String list which contains integer

Tags: java, string, sorting, integer

I want to sort a list of String that also contains numbers.

For example, I have a list containing elements `"1,2,3,4,5,11,12,21,22,31,32,A101,A102,A103,A104,B405"`.

If i use Collection.sort method means output is `"1,11,12,2,21,22,3,31,32... "`.

If i use Comparator function means it gives
 output as `"1,2,3,4,5,11,12,21,22,31,32,A101... ".`

But i need to display as

```
"A101,A102,A103,A104,B405,1,2,3,4,5,11,12,21,22,31,32"
```

Please any one give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is to make the Comparator implement the order you want to have.

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own comparator that tries to convert the objects to be compared to an integer, and if succesful, uses the compareTo of the Integer class, and otherwise uses the compareTo of the String class.

Like this:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String,String>
{
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
   {
       try
       {
           int i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
           int i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
           return i1 - i2;
       }
       catch (NumberFormatException e)
       {
           return s1.compareTo(s2);
       }
   }
}

ArrayList<String> myList = (...);
Collections.sort(myList,new MyComparator());
```

As commented, this sorts like this `1,12,A102,A103`. But wanted is: `A102,A103,1,12`. To do this we need to take care of situations where `s1` is parsable as int and `s2` is not and the other way around. I'm not sure if I got `-1` and `1` right, so maybe they should be swapped.

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String,String>
{
    public int compare(String s1, String s2)
   {
       Integer i1 = null
       Integer i2 = null
       try
       {
           i1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
       }
       catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
       try
       {
           i2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
       }
       catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
       if (i1 == null && i2 == null)
           return s1.compareTo(s2);
       if (i1 == null && i2 != null)
           return -1;
       if (i1 != null && i2 == null)
           return 1;
       return i1 - i2;
   }
}
```

Comment: This. But there's a typo in the first parameter, should be String s1.

Comment: I would replace the body of the `try {}` block with `new Integer(s1).compareTo(new Integer(s2))` or `Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1), Integer.parseInt(s2))`.

Comment: `new Integer(String s)` also calls `parseInt()` and throws a NFE, so that would purely be a matter of style.

Comment: But output is resulting in- 1 2 3 4 5 11 11 21 22 31 32 A101 A102 A103 A104 B405

Comment: That means we have to implement the situation where one is parsable to integer and the other is not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new "holder" object for the strings and implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. Override the "compareTo" method. That should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is present there in your question, just create two lists and sort them separately!

```
package com.kvvssut.misc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class SortStringThenNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1","5","3","4","2","11","11","21","31","32","22","A101","A103","A104","B405","A102"});
        List<Object> result = sortStringThenNumber(inputs);

        for (Object sorted : result) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(sorted));
        }
    }

    private static List<Object> sortStringThenNumber(List<String> inputs) {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String input : inputs) {
            if (input.matches("-?\\d+")) {
                numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(input));
            } else {
                strings.add(input);
            }
        }
        inputs = null;

        Collections.sort(numbers);
        Collections.sort(strings);

        ArrayList<Object> all = new ArrayList<Object>();
        all.addAll(strings);
        all.addAll(numbers);

        return all;
    }

}
```

Comment: output is - A101
A102
A103
A104
B405
1
2
3
4
5
11
11
21
22
31
32